# PG::UndefinedColumn after Rails rename column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

```
PG::UndefinedColumn at /books/17
ERROR:  column "books_count" does not exist at character 45
STATEMENT:  UPDATE "users" SET "books_count" = COALESCE("books_count", 0) - 1 WHERE "users"."id" = $1
```

I get the above error after changing running a name change in rails.

```
def change
    rename_column :users, :books_count, :books_shared
  end
```

I first noticed the problem when trying to delete a book. Otherwise, everything works. Is there a column in Postgresql that I have to change as well? Or should i revert the name change?

I already restarted the server.

EDIT: Current Schema

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "books_shared",           default: 0
    t.integer  "books_read",             default: 0
  end
```

books_shared WAS books_count. No other instances of books_count

Associations

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
      validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3}
      validates :author, presence: true
      has_many :book_checkouts
    end
```

Comment: do you have a :books_count column present in your db? also could you copy paste your table associations in your model.

Comment: After the migration, I searched through the entire app. No sign of books_count

Comment: well you changed your table name from books_count to books_share maybe thats why. Also you haven't posted your associations present in your model.

Comment: I think I found the problem, it is because of my counter cache being binded to books_count.

Answer (score 0):

By default Rails looks for the pluralized associated model followed by `_count`, which in your case was `books_count`.

Looks at the docs for `belongs_to` here and look for `counter_cache`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

You can specify a custom column name for the counter_cache on your Book class like so:

`belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :books_shared`